# jQuery - Simple slideToggle with multiple divs and additional hide function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a simple slideToggle with some additional functions. I have a function that hides a clicked div and toggle function to slide the remaining divs. Im having an error on the slide toggle, when i tried to toggle slide up the remaining divs, the hidden div will come off.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>jQuery Effects</h1>
    <button>Click Me!</button>
    <hr>

    <div><h2>One</h2></div>
    <div><h2>Two</h2></div>
    <div><h2>Three</h2></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    });

});

$("button").on("click", function(){
    $("div").slideToggle("slow", function(){

    })
});

let y = $("h1").text();

$("div").mouseenter(function(){
    let x = $(this).text();
    $("h1").text(x)
});

$("div").mouseleave(function(){
    $("h1").text(y)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update you `button` click as below.

In the `if` condition I have checked that when any of the `div` is `visible` then it will hide the `div` otherwise it will display all divs.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  if ($("div:visible").length > 0)
    $("div").fadeOut("slow");
  else
    $("div").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Below is complete code. I hope this is what you want.

**I suggest that you should use some css class for div and use those for fadeIn and fadeOut, In real application there can be more divs also.**

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
  if ($("div:visible").length > 0)
    $("div").fadeOut("slow");
  else
    $("div").fadeIn("slow");
});

let y = $("h1").text();

$("div").mouseenter(function() {
  let x = $(this).text();
  $("h1").text(x)
});

$("div").mouseleave(function() {
  $("h1").text(y)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery Effects</h1>
<button>Click Me!</button>
<hr>

<div>
  <h2>One</h2>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Two</h2>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Three</h2>
</div>
```